# onRequestPermissionsResult in Cordova android plugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions

I'm accessing the camera through Cordova plugin (android). For this, I'm asking `permission`  to the user. If the user clicks "allow" in `permission` dialog I have to start the camera. For this, in native android, I'm overriding `onRequestPermissionsResult` method like

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

So, i want to use `onRequestPermissionsResult` in Cordova plugin. Can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put that method in your plugins `.java` file it should work as usual. There is even good [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#runtime-permissions-cordova-android-500) on the topic of runtime permissions.
Request the permission works like this:

```
cordova.requestPermission(CordovaPlugin plugin, int requestCode, String permission);
```

And the callback method looks like this:

```
public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) throws JSONException {
  ... // you can find the whole example implementation in the docs
}
```

If you don't want to implement this yourself you can always use this handy plugin: [cordova-plugin-android-permissions](https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions) to request the camera permission.

**Edit (how to use the android-permissions plugin):**

```
var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;

permissions.hasPermission(permissions.CAMERA, function(status) {
  if (status.hasPermission) {
    // here you can savely start your own plugin because you already have CAMERA permission
  }
  else {
    // need to request camera permission
    permissions.requestPermission(permissions.CAMERA, success, error);

    function error() {
      // camera permission not turned on
    }

    function success(status) {
      if (status.hasPermission) {
        // user accepted, here you can start your own plugin
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you David, How can i use another plugin in my custom plugin?

Comment: You can't use another plugin in your custom plugin. You can use it in the .js code of your app. E.g. request camera permission using the android-permissions plugin and only start your own plugin if the user has granted the permission.

Comment: can you please share any example

Comment: I added a quick example to my answer, but you can find more detailed information on their github page.

Comment: You've any iOS equivalent for this?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey currently not possible to access the users camera on iOS 12. Primarily as Apple block WKWebView and UIWebView from access. A gestimate would be that we gain access in iOS 13 September 2019.